# Having conditions inside python generator functions

Tags: python, xml, file, iterator, generator

I have some txt file that I have to parse in some way. In the middle of the file there is a part formatted as XML data. 
I've written some class, with the following methods inside of them.

```
def generate_lines(self):
    start_line = self.get_starting_line()
    for idx, line in enumerate(open(self.log_file, 'r', encoding='ANSI')):
        if idx >= start_line:
            yield line
            if f'</{self.xml_tag}>' in line:
                break

def get_starting_line(self):
    for idx, line in enumerate(open(self.log_file, 'r', encoding='ANSI')):
        if f'<{self.xml_tag}>' in line:
            return idx

def get_xml_data(self):
    xml_data = ''
    for li in self.generate_lines():
        xml_data += li
    return xml_data
```

My solution **works fine** but I was wondering if having multiple conditions inside a generator methods is correct, or should I just write a simple one
like `lines = (line for line in open(self.log_file)` and that have a method that iterates over this generated lines with multiple conditions.

**What will be more clean, pythonic way.**

Comment: Use xml parser. There's built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or dozens of third party modules (e.g. [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/) )

Comment: Generally the expensive thing here is going to be reading the file. If the file is small and not done often, you're probably fine, but for large files you want to reduce that. Also, you're leaving open file handles around. You should be using a `with` block.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I am indeed using it inside the method that was not listed in the question. The thing is I need to parse a specified part from the file and from that part I need to create an xml.etree.ElementTree object. Only small part of the file is formatted as xml.

Comment: Related: [*Parse ASCII Text file containing XML in Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48161457/10824407), [*Extract XML Data from a text file using Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59483556/10824407), [*get only xml data from text file using python*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64442542/10824407).

Comment: @flakes So the expression ```for line in open(file): return line``` does not close the file?  How come?

Comment: Because that doesn't invoke the close method. You should do `with open(file) as f: for line in f: return line`

Comment: share the txt file (add it to the post) and explain what is the info you want to extract from the file.

Comment: @balderman I managed to get it done.

Comment: @Marcin, great, you can answer your own question.